# Avoider Game Tutorial: Score not working

Tags: string, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, super

I've been working on the tutorial for a neat avoider game over at this site: http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/2009/02/03/avoider-game-tutorial-5/ . I got as far as part 5, and up till then, I followed the code exactly (I stopped before running the final score at game over), and I event disabled auto-kernel and used device fonts, and embedded the text.

Except when I run the game, no matter how many enemies show up, my score doesn't change from 0.

Apparently, I keep getting the 1009 error, connected to the "onTick" function. I've concluded that it's connected to the "gameScore.addToValue( 5 );" line. But I don't know how to fix that. Can anyone help me?

Here's a sample of the code I've put in the classes in question, if anyone can spot something that I forgot to add.

--==--
Shooter_II class:
--==--

```
package 
{
  import flash.display.MovieClip;
  import flash.utils.Timer;
  import flash.events.TimerEvent;
  import flash.events.MouseEvent;
  import flash.events.Event;

  public class SpaceShooter_II extends MovieClip //The public class extends the class to a movie clip.
  { 
    public var army:Array; //the Enemies will be part of this array.
    public var gameScore:Score;
    public var playerShip:PlayerShip; //This establishes a variable connected to the PlayerShip AS.
    public var onScreen:GameScreen; //This establishes a variable that's connected to the GameScreen AS.
    public var gameTimer:Timer; //This establishes a new variable known as gameTimer, connected to the timer utility.

    //This function contains the bulk of the game's components.
    public function SpaceShooter_II() 
    {
      //This initiates the GameScreen.
      onScreen = new GameScreen;
      addChild ( onScreen );

      //This sets up the enemy army.
      army = new Array(); //sets the "army" as a NEW instance of array.
      var newEnemy = new Enemy( 100, -15); //This will create new enemies. There's new var newEnemy statement, hence we call THIS a var.
      army.push ( newEnemy ); //the new enemy is added to the army.
      addChild( newEnemy ); //the new enemy is added to the game.

      //This sets up the player's avatar, a spaceship.
      playerShip = new PlayerShip(); //This invokes a new instance of the PlayerShip... 
      addChild( playerShip ); //...And this adds it to the game.
      playerShip.x = mouseX; //These two variables place the "playerShip" on-screen...
      playerShip.y = mouseY; //...at the position of the mouse.


      //This sets up the gameTimer, where a lot of the action takes place.
      gameTimer = new Timer( 25 );
      gameTimer.addEventListener( TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick );
      gameTimer.start();
    }

      //This function contains the things that happen during the game (player movement, enemy swarms, etc.)
    public function onTick( timerEvent:TimerEvent ):void
    {
      //This "if" statement is where the array that contains the enemy ships is initialized.
      if ( Math.random() < 0.05 ) //This sets the number of ships showing up at once.
      {
        var randomX:Number = Math.random() * 800 //Generates a random number between 0 & 1.
        var newEnemy:Enemy = new Enemy ( randomX, -15 ); //This shows where the enemy starts out--at a random position on the X plane, but at a certain points on the Y plane.
        army.push( newEnemy ); //This adds the new enemy to the "army" Array.
    addChild( newEnemy ); //This makes the new enemy part of the game.

    //This piece of code is providing a 1009 error message that I don't know how to fix.
    gameScore.addToValue( 5 );//This adds a few points every time an enemy appears on-screen.
      }

      //This "for" statement sends the enemies downward on the screen.
      for each (var enemy:Enemy in army) //Every time an enemy is added to the "army" array, it's sent downward.
      {
        enemy.moveDown(); //This is the part that sends the enemy downward.

        //And now for the collision part--the part that establishes what happens if the enemy hits the player's spaceship:
        if ( playerShip.hitTestObject ( enemy ) ) //If the playerShip makes contact with the enemy...
        {
          gameTimer.stop(); //This stops the game.
          dispatchEvent( new PlayerEvent(PlayerEvent.BOOM) ); //This triggers the game over screen in the PlayerEvent AS

        }
      }

      //This, incidentally, is the player's movement controls:
      playerShip.x = mouseX;
      playerShip.y = mouseY;
    }

  } 
}
```

--==--
MainCounter class:
--==--

```
package
{
  import flash.display.MovieClip;
  public class MainCounter extends MovieClip
  {
    public var currentValue:Number;
    public var addedValue:Number;

    public function MainCounter()
      {
        resetValue(); //This triggers the resetValue function.
      }

      //This runs on every "tick," or every time that the player does something worthy of earning points.
      public function addToValue( addedValue:Number ):void
      {
        currentValue = currentValue + addedValue; //This takes the current value/score and updates it by adding an extra amount to it.
        updateDisplay(); //This triggers the updateDisplay function.
      }

      //This resets the time and score to the original value (zero). This is set off when the score/timer is created in the first place, and potentially if the player grabs a certain power-up or hits an enemy.
      public function resetValue():void
      {
        currentValue = 0; //this resets the current value/score/etc. to zero.
        updateDisplay(); //This triggers the updateDisplay function.
      }

      //This function shows the current score/time/whatever, and thus triggers every time the value changes.
      public function updateDisplay():void
      {

      }
  }
}
```

--==--
Score class:
--==--`

```
package  
{
    import flash.text.TextField;

    //The "extends" part of this class allows this class to "inherit" every public variable and function from the "MainCounter" class.
    public class Score extends MainCounter 
    {   
        public var scoreDisplay:TextField;

        public function Score() 
        {
            super(); //"super()" allows a class to access the functions of the class that it's "extending" to.
        }

            //This function is given an "override" because otherwise, we'd have two "updateDisplay" functions thanks to the "extends MainCounter."
            override public function updateDisplay():void
            {
                super.updateDisplay(); //Any code that's in the updateDisplay function of MainCounter will run here, too.
            scoreDisplay.text = currentValue.toString();
            //Fun fact: any sequence of letters and numbers is called a "string" because it's a string of characters. Case in point,
            //the text properties of this Score. Now, currentValue is defined as a Number, but all Numbers have a function called toString()
            //that returns the number in the form of a string.
            }

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `gameScore.addToValue( 5 )` as you have not created an instance of the Class Score.
You are calling it as if it is a static method when it is not. First try initializing an instance of Score.

Try this:

```
public var gameScore:Score = new Score();
```

now you should be able to call the `addtoValue` function.

Comment: Well, good news: I'm not getting that error anymore. The bad news is: the score remains lodged on zero when I play the game. Instead of giving me points whenever the enemy shows themselves, nothing happens at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't need to declare currentValue in your Score class as this is inherited from Main. This is probably why your score is 0, it is displaying the local currentValue rather than the value of the main class. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I modified the score class (and if you look up at my example, I edited what you see accordingly), and it still isn't working.

Comment: Where are you creating an instance of your scoreDisplay textfield and adding it to the display in this example, I can't see it?

Comment: What do you mean? It's in the "Score" class. Where in the display should I add it?

I mean, I assigned "scoreDisplay" to the instance name of my main scoreboard symbol. Then, when I put that symbol on the gamescreen, I gave That instance of the symbol the name "gameScore." Should I be doing something different?